# How does pthread_exit stop a thread from quitting before completion of its assigned task?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

`pthread_exit` when placed in main() before `return 0;` does stop a thread from quitting before completion of its assigned task.

I wish to understand the reasons *in detail*.

I put a while loop in the function that the thread was supposed to work on. 
The condition in the while didn't satisfy and yet the program terminated. When I put the pthread_exit in the main before return 0, the while loop completed its task.
Hence the question.

OS: Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning from `main()` with a return statement is equivalent to calling `exit()` --- it terminates the process, without waiting for other threads to finish.

Calling `pthread_exit()` just exits the thread that calls it (even if that thread is the one running `main()`), so other threads will keep running until either some thread calls `exit()` (or another function that terminates the process, such as `abort()`), or every thread has exited.

Comment: `main()` is a **function**. It is automatically called by the runtime library on the initial thread of the process. If you create more threads with `pthread_create()` then you have multiple threads in your process. You only get new processes with calls like `fork()` and `system()`.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean that one thread which runs the main() function is created by the process ? And the `return` statement exit the whole `process` even if only one thread calls it? And in order to preserve the remaining threads, we use `pthread_exit` which exits only the calling thread?

Comment: Yes. Just to be clear: it is only returning from `main()` that exits the process. Returning from any other function just returns from that function.

Comment: Anthony, can you please point me out to a resource where I can read about the main () thread. How it gets created and terminated?

Comment: The thread that calls `main()` is also called the "initial thread". It is created by the OS when the process is started, and terminated either by a call to `exit()` or a call to `pthread_exit()`, or by returning from the initial function of the thread (in this case, `main()`), just like every other thread.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Anthony, but is there any term which I can search in Google to read more about this?